# How to set places in listview which is from PlacesAPI other than Autocomplete?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to set the `AutoCompleteTextView` results in `Listview`. So the results comedown in `ListView` .I am trying too many times but i wont get the output. this is my code what i used in my program.

Please help me.

```
    tvStart_Location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            flag = 0;
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogue_auocomplete);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
            lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
            dialog.show();

            ivClear = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ivClear);
            tvCancel = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvCancel);
            tvStartLocation_one = (CustomAutoCompleteTextView) dialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvStartLocation_one);
            tvStartLocation_one.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int before, int count) {
                    placesTask = new PlacesTask();
                    placesTask.execute(s.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });

            tvStartLocation_one
                    .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View view, int position, long id) {
                            hideKeyboard(tvStartLocation_one);

                            st = tvStartLocation_one.getText().toString();
                            tvStart_Location.setText(st);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            try {
                                geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(),
                                        Locale.getDefault());
                                address1 = geocoder.getFromLocationName(st,
                                        5);
                                Address location1 = address1.get(0);
                                lat1 = (float) location1.getLatitude();
                                log1 = (float) location1.getLongitude();

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            ivClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    tvStartLocation_one.setText("");
                }
            });
            tvCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)

                {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: have you created a custom adapter for the autocompletetextview ?

Comment: @Brajesh Please Add Source Code .We all Are not sitting to Help Full Some Thing Work You Should Do For Self.Add Code....You Want We Make Your App Code

Comment: ACTV has its own dropdown list where it show suggestions, there is no need for a separate ListView